# Creating new structure for trees in C++

Tags: c++

I will keep it short. When I run the code, I enter the first character (e.g: 'k') and everything is fine. Second time I enter a character (e.g: 'j') I get an error and the compiler says that it is on the line (that has a comment). Please help. Thank you.

Code:

```
struct nodeType{
    char letter;
    nodeType*leftNode;
    nodeType*rightNode;

};
void putInNode(nodeType*n,char c){
    if ((char)(n->letter) >='a' && (char)(n->letter) <='z')/* ERROR IS HERE*/
    {
        if(n->letter < c)
            putInNode(n->leftNode, c);
        else
            putInNode(n->rightNode, c);
    }
    n->letter=c;
}
int main(){
    nodeType*a=new nodeType();
    char c;
    do {
        cin >> c;
        if(c=='.')
            break;
        putInNode(a,c);
    } while (true);
    cout << a->letter << endl;

}
```

Comment: And _what_ error do you get? Please include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message.

Comment: By the way, you should really create a constructor that makes the pointers null, and also **check** for null, or you will step around in memory until your program crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the purpose of this is to build a tree of only letters from the input stream, stopping when you reach a period, and skipping anything that is not in `{'a'...'z'}`, I think this is what you're after:

```
#include <iostream>

struct nodeType
{
    nodeType(char ch = 0)
       : letter(ch), leftNode(), rightNode()
    {}

    char letter;
    nodeType* leftNode;
    nodeType* rightNode;
};

void putInNode(nodeType*& n,char c)
{
    if (!n)
    {
        n = new nodeType(c);
    }
    else if (n->letter >='a' && n->letter <='z')
    {
        if(c < n->letter)
            putInNode(n->leftNode, c);
        else
            putInNode(n->rightNode, c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    nodeType* a = NULL;
    char c;
    while ((std::cin >> c) && c != '.')
        putInNode(a,c);

    if (a)
        std::cout << a->letter << '\n';
}
```

Note: this pushes duplicates down the *right* child line. If this is not the intention, change the following:

```
        if(c < n->letter))
            putInNode(n->leftNode, c);
```

to this instead:

```
        if(c <= n->letter)) // <== note less-or-equal
            putInNode(n->leftNode, c);
```

I leave the cleanup of the resulting dynamic tree to you. And it should be noted that as-written (both prior and now) the first node will always be the root of your tree (I assume someday you're planning on balancing via shifts and such as you move further down this road).

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that the problem is that you're not actually allocating any nodes appart from the root node.  Therefore, when you enter the second letter, the first letter has already set the letter in the parent node, and when it tries to dereference the left node in the tree, it fails (b/c that's unallocated memory).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are only allocating space for a single node and not initializing your variables.

First time through the `do` loop I assume `a->letter = 0` so when entering the `putInNode` function the letter will be assigned to `k`. Next time through the loop `n->letter` will be `k` which is in between `a` and `z` and `k < j` will be true so `putInNode(n->leftNode, c);`

`n->leftNode` has not been initialized however so when you try to deference it like `n->letter` you will get a segfault.

To fix this (assuming you do not want this function to make new nodes) is to create a constructor for your struct then check for null.

```
struct nodeType{
  nodeType() 
  {
    letter    = 0;
    leftNode  = nullptr;
    rightNode = nullptr;
  }
  char letter;
  nodeType*leftNode;
  nodeType*rightNode;
};
```

Then in `putInNode`

```
void putInNode(nodeType*n,char c){
   if(n == nullptr) {
      return;
   }
   if ((char)(n->letter) >='a' && (char)(n->letter) <='z') {
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Thank you guys very very much. I am new to this field, that's why it might seem like a silly question. But I appreciate it a lot. Problem is solved.